# Get textinput number of character in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4.6

I have textinput in flex we application.

```
<s:TextInput id="txtGuestCount" maxChars="2" editable="false"/>
```

Where i limit `maxChars` to 2. It works when i remove `editable="false"` from textinput and type using keyboard.

**Problem:** 
But same thing is not works when i do using button click like:

```
<s:Button width="50" height="50"  chromeColor="#ffffff" label="1" buttonMode="true" click="onNumberClick(event)"/>
<s:Button width="50" height="50"  chromeColor="#ffffff" label="2" buttonMode="true" click="onNumberClick(event)"/>
<s:Button width="50" height="50"  chromeColor="#ffffff" label="3" buttonMode="true" click="onNumberClick(event)"/>
<s:Button width="50" height="50"  chromeColor="#ffffff" label="4" buttonMode="true" click="onNumberClick(event)"/>
<s:Button width="50" height="50"  chromeColor="#ffffff" label="5" buttonMode="true" click="onNumberClick(event)"/>
<s:Button width="50" height="50"  chromeColor="#ffffff" label="6" buttonMode="true" click="onNumberClick(event)"/>
<s:Button width="50" height="50"  chromeColor="#ffffff" label="7" buttonMode="true" click="onNumberClick(event)"/>
<s:Button width="50" height="50"  chromeColor="#ffffff" label="8" buttonMode="true" click="onNumberClick(event)"/>
<s:Button width="50" height="50"  chromeColor="#ffffff" label="9" buttonMode="true" click="onNumberClick(event)"/>
<s:Button width="50" height="50"  chromeColor="#ffffff" label="0" buttonMode="true" click="onNumberClick(event)"/>
```

On click of button insertlabel value in textinput like:

```
protected function onNumberClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   txtGuestCount.text += event.currentTarget.label;
}
```

The above thing is not working. It will insert more than 2 character in `textInput`.

Any one help me to figure-out this issue? 
How can i restrict max 2 character in textinput?

Comment: The limit is only for user input, you can add any number of character by code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/TextInput.html#maxChars), `maxChars` is not checked when `text` is altered in code. So, you have to manually control the new value of `text` to not exceed 2 chars. An example:

```
protected function onNumberClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var s:String=txtGuestCount.text;
    if (s.length==2) s=s.substr(1); // drop first char
    s+=event.currentTarget.label;
    // if (s.length>2) s=s.substr(0,2); // if necessary, truncate
    txtGuestCount.text = s;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Really great solution. Is there any way to stop entering new value instead of change? like if i click on 09 then press 1 nothing happen instead of 91?

Comment: sure there is, `if (s.length>=2) return;` instead of calling `substr()`.